# Raycasting as collision detector: not accurate

Tags: javascript, three.js, raycasting

I got a scene with multiple random forms (like triangles, trapezoids, but also more custom designs), and I'm trying to write the code for the collision detection. The shapes are all 2D and are location on `Y=0`

As the forms are more complicated than just circles and rectangles, I decided to use raycasting to check for collisions.

```
 var raycastCollision = function () {

        var originPoint = activeElement.position.clone();
        var vertices = activeElement.geometry.vertices;


        //loop
        for (var vertexIndex = 0; vertexIndex < vertices.length; vertexIndex++) {

            var localVertex = vertices[vertexIndex].clone();
            var globalVertex = localVertex.applyMatrix4(activeElement.matrix);
            var directionVector = globalVertex.sub(activeElement.position);

            var ray = new THREE.Raycaster(originPoint, directionVector.clone().normalize(),true);
            ray.ray.direction.y = 0;
            var collisionResults = ray.intersectObjects(elements);
            debug["ray" + vertexIndex] = ray;
            if (collisionResults.length > 0 && collisionResults[0].object != activeElement && collisionResults[0].distance < directionVector.length()) {

                debug["raycast detection"] = "HIT";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

`ActiveElement` is the current selected shape, and `elements` is the list of all shapes on scene.

The problem I have is that it only detects "hits" in certain situations, and I've not been able yet to pinpoint in what situations that is. But 1 thing is sure: it more often than not, doesn't detect a hit when it should.

Can anyone detect the error(s) in my code?

Edit: example pictures of a "no hit" and a "hit" situation
[image: hit]

[image: No hit]

Comment: Is activeElement.position a worldSpace coordinate and are these tirangles you test parallel to each other? Does collisionResults just contain one element and if so, is it self intersecting? ( I thought so because of your conditions in the if-statement)

Ahh and why is the y coordinate of the ray set to 0? This would project it onto the xz-plane right?

Comment: @TOAOGG Position: local position relative to the parent. But in this case: the parent is the "world", so it's worldspace. Triangles are on same Y-axis (both Y = 0) so in theory: yes they are parallel, but they're also immediately overlapping.
`collissionResults` contains no elements, it's an empty array (the self-check condition in my `if` is not necessary, it's overkill)

Comment: So to get the direction vector,  you need both (globalVertex and originPoint) in global/world space right? 

Also setting the y component of the ray will stick it to the xz-plane so intersections will just be detected on this plane.

collisionResults[0].distance < directionVector.length()

should be 

collisionResults[0].distance > directionVector.length()

as you want results outside of your object, not insight right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As my old answer is not correct, I removed it.

I tried your function on a test scene and the following solution works:

https://jsfiddle.net/qzL9L38a/

I guess the problem are the parallel faces in your case.

For spheres the following works:

```
var raycastCollision = function () {

var originPoint = spheres[0].position.clone();
var vertices = spheres[0].geometry.vertices;


//loop
for (var vertexIndex = 0; vertexIndex < vertices.length; vertexIndex++) {

    var localVertex = vertices[vertexIndex]; // no need to clone if applyMatrix4 won'T change localVertex.
    var globalVertex = localVertex.applyMatrix4(spheres[0].matrix);
    var directionVector = globalVertex.sub(originPoint);

    var ray = new THREE.Raycaster(originPoint, directionVector.clone().normalize(),true);
    var collisionResults = ray.intersectObjects(spheres);
    collisionResults = collisionResults.filter(function(element)
    {
      return element.distance < directionVector.length();                                         
    });
    if (collisionResults.length > 0 ) {

        console.log('HIT: '+collisionResults);
        break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: ok, so it must be because they are "flat".. Now the question: how can I make an invisible copy that isn't flat and use that instead? :) (thx a lot already btw!)

Comment: Will they always be parallel planes? Maybe a 2D Collision Detection approach checking directionVector -> Edge intersections might fit more. 

I'm not sure how this is solved by default, but you could also apply a small offset rotation to your directionVector so that it is not exactly parallel to the tested face anymore.

Comment: You wouldn't have an example of 2D collision detection somewhere close, by any chance, do you?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Joncom/e8e8d18ebe7fe55c3894

You should try this on each edge of your active mesh against each edge of the target mesh.

To speed things up, axis aligned bounding boxes can be used first, and if they are coliding, you can test the actual edges.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) your example above works amazingly, I did, as you said, implement double checking: first bounding boxes, and if those hit, then the extra calculations, to avoid overload. I'm using the raycasting in your original answer to check my 3D objects that are also in my scene. So all works now!